# When Executing the P4 annotate command Getting Remote Server Error

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I have a cpp file path and Function Name written in that file for which I am trying to fetch the Changelist when that function was written. Using the command as below:

```
p4 annotate -I filename.cpp | findstr "function Name"
```

when executing above command in cmd getting the following error:

```
Remote depot 'server' database access failed.
Remote server refused request. Please verify that service user is correctly logged in to remote server, then retry.
connect: Connection timed out
```

what is going wrong here? This is happening for some files only , for other files command is executing suucessfully and returning the changelist.

Answer (score 1):

The file in question has merge ancestors that are in a remote depot, and the remote depot is currently unavailable, so displaying the full merge history (with annotate -I) is failing.  Check with your Perforce admin to either restore access to the remote depot or (if it's permanently dead) obliterate it so your local server doesn't keep trying to query it.

Comment: Thanks Samwise for the reply. Will check at my end.